# Using WSO2 as identity Provider for docebo system

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, integration, saml-2.0

I have a Docebo LMS system, I have created SAML SSO for this system through okta,  I am trying to use opensource IDP which is WSO2, I am using it in localhost server. I have created IDP that I will be using it to provide the identity authentication through the docs provided in WSO2. The problem that I am not able to see the login page. It's showing me these 3 lines:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akmyy.png)

I have Docebo as staging system which is uploaded Docebo SAAS server.

Any help regards this issue. ?!

Comment: First, have a look at the WSO2 IS logs from `<WSO2_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log` to get an idea on the issue

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2019-07-22 11:10:23,639] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager} -  Error while adding Identity provider in tenantDomain : carbon.super